# Getting an item from the MSMQ Journal, which WCF created

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have a message in a Journal of a Private queue (.\Private$\theQueue\Journal$)

The message was created by WCF and processed (thus on the Journal).

The problem is I want to get the message (the body is too large to view in the Admin Tools) so i have created the following code

```
MessageQueue myQueue = new MessageQueue(txtQueueName.Text);
Message peekByLookupId = myQueue.PeekById(txtLookUpId.Text);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(peekByLookupId.BodyStream);
txtResult.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

but the StreamReader does not return any result for the ReadToEnd. however the Stream does have a length (peekByLookupId.BodyStream.Length) of 1676

does any one have the code to peek at the XML of the object which WCF created (using the DataContractFormatter)

Or does anyone know where is the DataContractFormatter, as i could use this deserialise the object. (I have added the System.Runtime.Serialization to the project and it still does not recognise the object)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I pulled out the body stream as bytes (do not convert into a string). converted into hex and viewed in WinHex..

there has to be a better way